# Code Cleanup doesn't do Format document in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, code-cleanup

I have the following settings regarding my Tab sizing in Visual Studio 17.4.1:

[image]

When I use *Edit->Advanced->Format Document*, I get this result:

[image]

I configured *Code Cleanup* which allegedly contains *Format Document*:

[image]

When I save or explicitely use it, I get this result:

[image]

Are there two separate Format Document commands? How should I get the same result?

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I use Visual Studio Community 2022 with Unity, and I had the same issue.

If I launch Visual Studio and click Open Folder to add a project, Code Cleanup won't work. However, if I open a file from Unity, it will launch Visual Studio, and Code Cleanup will work. I can then press Show All Files in Solution Explorer to see the rest of the files.